# How To add Flurry SDK to WP7 project?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dll, windows-phone, flurry

I have a WP7 project and i want to add Flurry for Analytics and there is no WP7 sdk on there site when i contacted them in support they said " the Flurry WP8 SDK v3.1.2 which is backward compatible with WP7.x apps." 
But when tried to add to my app Visual studio said "A reference to higher version or incompatible assembly cannot added to project"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WP8 SDK isn't backwards-compatible the last I checked - I had to get a specific WP7 SDK .dll file from their support to get it working. I'd contact them again to let them know that it isn't backwards-compatible, and that you need the WP7 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This dll version is backwards compatible, and the message you are seeing is often an error that has to do with "unblocking" the dll. Could you please verify if you've tried the following steps?

1. Unzip the dll - right-click on the file
2. Select Properties, click "Unblock", and then save the change

(Full disclosure: I work at Flurry)

Comment: I tried this with version 3.1.1 and it didn't work. How do we download version 3.1.2?